# GAE: java.sql.SQLException: Transient error, please try again

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, database-connection, google-cloud-sql, jdbc-pool

db.DbTransaction getConnection: null

```
java.sql.SQLException: Transient error, please try again.
    at 

    com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.makeSyncCall(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:108)
        at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.openConnection(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:71)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:58)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:66)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:26)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)
        at db.DbTransaction.getConnection(DbTransaction.java:44)
```

When i restarted the instance of Google Cloud SQL, it is resolved. What the reason behind it and how can i solve it. I have used servlet based connection pooling in this application. Whether the cause of exception have an relation to connection pooling or have any issue related to  **An App Engine instance cannot have more than 30 concurrent connections to Google Cloud SQL, so a leak will eventually cause new connections to fail** (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/).